# How to fill dictionaries values by using the for loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have three lists, each contains a unique ID of the employee. For example,

```
bug = [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
task = [1,1,1,1,2,9]
subtask = [10, 11, 11, 11, 8, 8, 8, 8 ,8 , 8, 6]
```

The number of references of employee ID shows, how many issues were solved by the employee. For example, employee with ID=1 solved 1 bug, 4 tasks and 0 subtasks. I want to create a dictionary, which has the next structure: keys are IDs of employees and values are list of size 3, each value of list shows how much bugs, tasks and subtasks employee with ID = something solved. For example, in my case I have to obtain the next dictionary:

```
all_employees = {1:[1, 4, 0], 2:[1, 1, 0], 3:[1, 0, 0], 4:[5, 0, 0], 5:[1, 0, 0], 6:[1, 0, 1], \
                 7:[1, 0, 1], 8:[3, 0, 6], 9:[0, 1, 0], 10:[0, 0, 1], 11:[0, 0, 3]}
```

This is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
bug = [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
task = [1,1,1,1,2,9]
subtask = [10, 11, 11, 11, 8, 8, 8, 8 ,8 , 8, 6]
all_issues = bug + task + subtask
all_emlpoyees = dict.fromkeys(all_issues, [0, 0, 0])    
bug_d = dict(Counter(bug))
task_d = dict(Counter(task))
subtask_d = dict(Counter(subtask))
for i in all_employees.keys():
    try:
        print("value = ", bug_d[i])
        print ("key = ", i)

        all_employees[i][0] = bug_d[i]
    except Exception as e:
        pass
print (all_assignees)
```

In my opinion, this code should produce the same dictionary, as mentioned above, but only with one, first, non-zero value at its lists, but my output looks like:

```
{1: [3, 0, 0], 2: [3, 0, 0], 3: [3, 0, 0], 4: [3, 0, 0], 5: [3, 0, 0], 6: [3, 0, 0], 7: [3, 0, 0], 8: [3, 0, 0], 9: [3, 0, 0], 10: [3, 0, 0], 11: [3, 0, 0]}
```

in spite of two prints at the for loop shows correct values. 
Any ideas, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help, issue solved.

Comment: You only set `all_employees[i][0]` - you never set `all_employees[i][1]` = `task_d[i]` or `all_employees[i][2] = subtask_d[i]`

Comment: Why would you do `except Exception as e:
        pass` ?? What's the purpose of `dict(Counter(bug))` ? Isn't `collections.Counter` a subclass of dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one line of code:

```
bug = [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
task = [1,1,1,1,2,9]
subtask = [10, 11, 11, 11, 8, 8, 8, 8 ,8 , 8, 6]

{i:[bug.count(i), task.count(i), subtask.count(i)] for i in set(bug+task+subtask)}

Out[1]:
{1: [1, 4, 0],
 2: [1, 1, 0],
 3: [1, 0, 0],
 4: [5, 0, 0],
 5: [1, 0, 0],
 6: [1, 0, 1],
 7: [1, 0, 0],
 8: [3, 0, 6],
 9: [0, 1, 0],
10: [0, 0, 1],
11: [0, 0, 3]}
```

it's the same like using loop:

```
for i in set(bug+task+subtask):
    a[i] = [bug.count(i), task.count(i), subtask.count(i)]

print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map the lists as a list of `Counter` first, so that you can create the desired dict by iterating over a set of all the keys:

```
counts = list(map(Counter, (bug, task, subtask)))
all_employees = {id: [c[id] for c in counts] for id in {id for c in counts for id in c}}
```

`all_employees` becomes:

```
{1: [1, 4, 0], 2: [1, 1, 0], 3: [1, 0, 0], 4: [5, 0, 0], 5: [1, 0, 0], 6: [1, 0, 1], 7: [1, 0, 0], 8: [3, 0, 6], 9: [0, 1, 0], 10: [0, 0, 1], 11: [0, 0, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count from each of the list and then create a dictionary.
This avoids counting the number of tasks for each employee.

```
>>> c1, c2, c3 = Counter(bug), Counter(task), Counter(subtask) 
>>> d={}
>>> for employee in set(c1)|set(c2)|set(c3):
...     d[employee] = [c1[employee], c2[employee], c3[employee]]
... 
>>> d
{1: [1, 4, 0], 2: [1, 1, 0], 3: [1, 0, 0], 4: [5, 0, 0], 5: [1, 0, 0], 6: [1, 0, 1], 7: [1, 0, 0], 8: [3, 0, 6], 9: [0, 1, 0], 10: [0, 0, 1], 11: [0, 0, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The required output can be achieved using following piece of code.

```
bug = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8]
task = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9]
subtask = [10, 11, 11, 11, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6]

# first create a set of all employee id , no repeats
all_employees = set(bug + task + subtask)

# loop over each id and find the count of bug, task, sub_task and append it in the dict
final_dict = {}
for id in all_employees:
    final_dict[id] = [bug.count(id), task.count(id), subtask.count(id)]

print(final_dict)
```

Output :

```
{1: [1, 4, 0], 2: [1, 1, 0], 3: [1, 0, 0], 4: [5, 0, 0], 5: [1, 0, 0], 6: [1, 0, 1], 7: [1, 0, 0], 8: [3, 0, 6], 9: [0, 1, 0], 10: [0, 0, 1], 11: [0, 0, 3]}
```

Comment: The use of the `list.count` method in a loop unnecessarily makes it *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity.

Comment: @blhsing could you suggest better approach?

Comment: Convert the lists to frequency dicts with `collections.Counter` so that you can lookup the count for each ID with *O(1)* time complexity, resulting in a time complexity of *O(n)* overall.

Comment: Nice. Wasn't aware of  `collections.Counter`. Thanks !!